# How can I disable a plugin in a module from another module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin

I've installed a vendor module which as a plugin in its `di.xml`.

What I intend to do is to write my own module to disable the plugin in that vendor module as I wanted to have my own functionalities for a particular part. Although I can modify that module's `di.xml` by setting its `disabled` attribute to true, since it's a vendor module, I try to avoid modifying it directly.

How can I disable a plugin in module A from **another** module B?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: just saw that you already tried the solution below. AFAIK it's the only "clean" way of doing it

You can add the following in your own `di.xml`

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
        <plugin name="{pluginName}" disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Make sure your own module depends on the 3rd party module

Comment: How can I make sure that my module depends on the 3rd party module